# Installing jovian in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I am new to Python. I was trying to install jovian in jupyter notebook using the command '!pip install jovian --upgrade' but getting the below error: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[1],
line 1 ----> 1 get_ipython().system('pip install jovian
--upgr
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().system('pip install jovian --upgrade')

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2590, in InteractiveShell.system_piped(self, cmd)
2585     raise OSError("Background processes not supported.")
2587 # we explicitly do NOT return the subprocess status code, because
2588 # a non-None value would trigger :func:`sys.displayhook` calls.
2589 # Instead, we store the exit_code in user_ns.
-> 2590 self.user_ns['_exit_code'] = system(self.var_expand(cmd, depth=1))

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py:129, in ProcessHandler.system(self, cmd)
125 enc = DEFAULT_ENCODING
127 # Patterns to match on the output, for pexpect.  We read input and
128 # allow either a short timeout or EOF
--> 129 patterns = [pexpect.TIMEOUT, pexpect.EOF]
130 # the index of the EOF pattern in the list.
131 # even though we know it's 1, this call means we don't have to worry if
132 # we change the above list, and forget to change this value:
133 EOF_index = patterns.index(pexpect.EOF)

AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoBOr.png)

Comment: Try installing from `Anaconda Prompt` instead of `Jupyter Notebook`

Comment: What version of Jupyter are you using here? Have you updated and installed it recently? What kernel are you running. It should be indicated in the upper right corner. By the way, using an exclamation point in conjunction with installs is no longer advised in modern Jupyter. You'll have better experience using the magic commands, see my comments below [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76979465/8508004). What makes you think Ankita has Anaconda installed, @Bhargav?  I'm not seeing it in any paths.

Comment: I see their own documentation [here](https://jovian-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/install.html) is outdated in regards to best practices, Ankita. (And in fact hasn't been updated in three years according to [here](https://github.com/JovianHQ/jovian-py/blob/master/docs/user-guide/install.md).) (And other versions, such as [here](https://jovian.com/aakashns/jovian-tutorial) contain hijacked or broken links, too. For example, the link in the text "or Click Here to start a Jupyter notebook server "). In light of this, I'd take some of their guidance cautiously.

Comment: If you'd like to have place to compare where the Jovian installation will work without touching your own system yet. Go to [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and click the '`launch binder`' badge. A temporary, anonymous session on a remote machine will spin up. Click the 'Python 3 (ipykernel)' tile under 'Notebook' in the main panel to start a new notebook. Then enter in the new notebook, the command `%pip install jovian` and run that cell. Let it complete and you'll see it works. Note the session is temporary & download anything you make to your local machine ASAP.

Comment: Actually I have not installed anything in my local machine. I was just practicing in the web version of jupyter notebook and in order to save everything in a document format I was trying to import jovian, so to import jovian, is it necessary to install Anaconda locally. Sorry the question might be very silly but I am absolutely new to python